# Error C2057 expected constant expression while using a constant

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, size

Here is my problem, I must be missing something here.

```
 const int nfft = 256 * 1024;
const float samplefrequency = 256.0 * 1024.0 ; // Hz

/* The buffer, spectral and data arrays for the FFT */
kiss_fft_cfg mybuff;
kiss_fft_cpx samples[nfft];
kiss_fft_cpx fftoutput[nfft];

/* The final, averaged spectrum */
double finalspec[nfft/2];
```

So this is a part of my code.

The problem is that i can't compile it because of :
"error C2057: expression constante attendue" line 16 -  kiss_fft_cpx samples[nfft];
"error C2057: constant expression required"

I don't understand what is wrong considering the fact that nfft is a constant.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand what is wrong considering the fact that nfft is a
>   constant

In C `const` variables **aren't really constants**, more like read-only objects. As such, they can't be used in all the places where true constants could be used (for example the size of an array).

Perhaps you could use a macro instead:

```
#define NFFS (256 * 1024)
```

---

Incidentally there's also a C FAQ entry on this subject: [*I don't understand why I can't use const values in initializers and array dimensions*](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html).